# Is this bug on when set the max size on the TextField while use LWUIT with Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textfield

I set the `TextField` max size to 20. Its working fine. And i got the warning alert like **`Field Full`** when I reach. There is no issues. And there is no any other components in the `Form`. Only one `TextField` placed in the `Form`.

But issue is After that warning alert, I pressed down key or up key. Its focused `TextField` itself. And then I pressing delete key for deleting characters in the `TextField`. That time I'm getting the `illegalargumentexception`. Why this exception occur?

**Update:**

```
  TextField searchTxtField = new TextField(); 
  searchTxtField.setMaxSize(20);
  searchTxtField.addDataChangeListener(new DataChangedListener() {
   public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
        .....
        .....
      }
    });
```

Comment: can you please upload your code ?

Comment: @ Lucifer, I updated the code. Also There is no issues with this code.

Comment: What you are doing with DataChangeListener ?

Comment: @ Siva, Just searching the words in the `List`. I think its not an issue. Because its working fine in the Symbian devices. But Problem occurs only on Blackberry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an illegal argument exception issue with the native blackberry port. I think it should be resolved in the current version in SVN. If you still get this exception with the latest SVN code please provide us with a stack trace (from the device log).